# Is this run out legal?

Tags: rules, cricket

I saw this situation in a local cricket match.

> Fielder drops bails of the wicket mistakenly before he has received the ball in hand.After that he touches the ball to the wicket.Umpire gives out.

Is this legal?Shouldn't he have fixed the bails again before making the batsman out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Law 38](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-38-run-out/) covers run out. However, in this case it's [Law 28 - Wicket down](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-28-the-wicket-is-down/) that is the relevant one.

In the case above, Law 28 section 1, clause V covers it - if both bails are dislodged, the fielder can effect a runout by either replacing a bail (as you suggest, although only 1 bail is required) OR by removing a stump from the ground **with the ball in the same hand as the stump**.

The old fable of taking out a stump and touching the ball to it while held over the head is simply that, a fable.

In your question, I think the umpire erred in giving the runout, unless bails had been dispensed with - see section 4 of law 28.